# How to add custom headers to request of AsyncImage in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to use [AsyncImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage) and I don't know how to add custom headers to request. Is there some kind of way to do it?

Comment: that would be nice would it. I have the same problem where the request needs to have the authorization header to be able to get through. Anybody has a solution?